# MonoDroid Camera.IshutterCalBack

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Can someone please post how to convert the java below to c# (monodroid)?

```
// Handles data for raw picture
  PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() { // <7>
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't allow for anonymous classes like Java does, so you have to define a class that implements the interface (`PictureCallback` in Java, `IPictureCallback` in Mono for Android):

```
private class PictureCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Hardware.Camera.IPictureCallback 
{
    public void  OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
}
```